# How can i execute external script or function which generate random mail in mail field in the protractor script

Tags: angular, protractor

The protractor script is just login form but I want in the field where is email to have a function which generates random mail or use an external script which generates random mail :

browser.driver.findElement(by.id('fullname')).sendKeys('LQLQLQLQ');
    browser.sleep(5000);

browser.driver.findElement(by.id('mobile')).sendKeys('899999888');
    browser.sleep(5000);

```
getRandomEmail = function () {
var strValues = "abcdefghijk123456789";
var strEmail = "";
for (var i = 0; i < strValues.length; i++) {
    strEmail = strEmail + strValues.charAt(Math.round(strValues.length * Math.random()));
}
return strEmail + "@mymail.test";
};
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).executeScript('getRandomEmail');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return an email address ending in '@mymail.test' of a length specified.

```
var randomEmail = function (emailLength) {
        var possible = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        function pickRandom() {
            return possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)];
        };
        var strEmail = Array.apply(null, Array(emailLength)).map(pickRandom).join('');
        return strEmail + '@mymail.test';
    };
```

You can then just call it like this:

```
element(by.id('fullname')).sendKeys('LQLQLQLQ');
element(by.id('mobile')).sendKeys('899999888');
element(by.id('email')).sendKeys(randomEmail(10));
```

Note that you shouldn't need to use `browser.sleep()` at all.